# Images not shown in firefox portable

Tags: bug, images, top-bar, firefox

I used stackoverflow sice some days in firefox portable version 49.0.2. There are the images at the beginning of the top bar missing:

[image]

Also the images for the editor i can not see:
[image]

Is it a bug or is firefox portable not supported by stackoverflow?
Or can it be a problem with browser settings.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: @Cerbrus That is a new installation

Comment: Something on your end refuses to load or run javascript or something got injected that breaks the JS. Try top load the site over https.

Comment: @rene Thanks that is the solution. But why the image is shown, if you get a message or a reputation change?

Comment: It might be that the websocket listener did start and that subsequent ajax calls on receiving a frame over the websocket did work? Anyone's guess is fine here ;)